# Probablity distributions/confidence score for each bounding box for Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Normally we have the only one confidence score for each bounding box that is printed for each  detected object. My understanding is that for each detected Tensorflow Object Detection API has multiple scores but finally  it uses argmax to print name of the object having the highest one. Now if If I want to print all the scores (not just the highest one), where can I find them?

Comment: Hi @Mahdi,  can you give more context on your question? Can you give a minimum reproducible code?

Comment: My question is regarding the confidence score for each object of an image. For example, if an image has two object but the dataset  is of 10 objects, so supposedlly we need to have: 
First object)  Dog 90%, cat 3%, computer 1% ... (A total of 100%)

Comment: Hi @Mahdi, Are you talking about this tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb?

Comment: Yes, I followed this and few others but the idea is the same, `output_dict['detection_scores']` display the maximum score for a bounding box, where to get all the scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the scores and respective labels for the image using `output_dict` which will contain all the information for the image about `detection_scores`, `detection_classes`, `detection_boxes` and `num_detections`.

For a given image you can just simply do the following to print all the scores of the objects detected.

```
all_scores ={}
image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
#Actual detection.
output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
for cls_idx,scr in zip(output_dict["detection_classes"],output_dict["detection_scores"]):
   all_scores[cls_idx] = scr
```

The output of `all_scores` looks something like this:

```
{1: 0.044680625,
 3: 0.05898307,
 9: 0.051253375,
 16: 0.04842608,
 18: 0.0313316,
 21: 0.031728894,
 33: 0.13961948,
 34: 0.07948237,
 38: 0.044567253,
 42: 0.047603823,
 47: 0.030417146,
 57: 0.0398438,
 62: 0.032532312,
 63: 0.04614881,
 84: 0.0338195,
 88: 0.036108077}
```

You can map the index name with the category name if you want the name to be printed.

Hope this answeres your question, Happy Learning.

Comment: @Mahdi - If you think i have answered your question, please UpVote and accept the answer, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of the Object Detection API (corresponding to TensorFlow version 2.2) the dictionary that contains the detections has the following keys:

```
dict_keys([
'raw_detection_boxes',
'detection_multiclass_scores',
'raw_detection_scores', 
'detection_anchor_indices', 
'detection_scores',
'detection_boxes',
'detection_classes',
'num_detections'])
```

The `detection_multiclass_scores` is the one that corresponds to the scores for all classes per detection (not just the highest). So if you want to see them you would do something like:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_directory)
detections = model(input_tensor)
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                for key, value in detections.items()}
print(detections['detection_multiclass_scores'])
```

where your `model_directory` is the directory that has the saved model and the `input_tensor` is the image you want to inference as a tensor.

If I'm not mistaken (and please correct me if I am) these scores are not available for older versions of the Object Detection API.